# Integrating magento facebook -login working in localhost but not in Live

Tags: php, facebook

Hi i am having the serious problem regarding the magento and facebook connect. I have used the facebook extension of inchoo along with fontis recaptcha . and paypal login. I havev having the problem with login in live server but  it is running in localhost. I have also set up the application in the facebook and used the secret key and app Id.Any help will be hignly appreciated.
Regards,
Samit

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your

1. App key is correct
2. Secret Jey is correct
3. It has the same url which is registered in the facebook App.

These are three main reason that cause when you are working with facebook login.

Comment: i have used in subdomain. ie  I have registered in draft.domain.net and also using it in draft.domain.net

Comment: Its fine ...what is the actual problem you are faceing

Comment: I am getting the following Facebook connection failed. Service temporarily unavailable.

Comment: if you create this app recently then it might take some time to get activated. I don't think there is any error with the code.

Comment: There is no problem in facebook app as its working well may be the problem with the module.

Comment: but if the problem in the module it should not have worked in localhost. Its really confusing. isn't it

Comment: ya its confusing. I have also gone through such problem but that was the problem in app key. please let me know the module name which you have used